# SL 'Composite' Navigation Application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism

In a silverlight composite application, is it possible to implement navigation, so that the back and forward buttons would be functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article (http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html) written by Jeremy Likness. He is using Prism and Navigation framework and its a good article to get you going with.

The "Navigated" on the Navigation Frame object will be called whenever the user click on the browser back or forward button.

Hopefully this is enough to get you going.  If you have any more questions just let me know.